KATE regex match extends to all the way to next match
I'm running Debian/Trixie on an AMD64 system. I'm using KATE to convert a text file I created using egrep to extract an organization name & id in brackets, and also the chief officer. I needed some extra information about the officer so I had to print some extra lines after each match - so I've got lines after the organization name because I needed lines after the officer name.
The command line was:
egrep "\([0-9]+\)|President" -A5  filename.text >Presidents.text

where the first bit matches the org id (in brackets) or the position title I want. This would produce a file with multiple repetitions of something like:
    org name (12345)
    org founding date
  other org information
     ...
     ...
  last line of org info
Officer Name                 Officer Title
officer info 1               Other info 1
Officer info 2
Officer info 3
Officer info 4
officer info 5

Now I want to get rid of the excess lines after the organization name & id. The line would look like "...multiple spaces...organization name (12345)" so my regex to match it is
^\s+([^\(]+\(\d+\))$

since the brackets only appear in those lines. This works and captures the name & id. The idea is that having found that line, I can can extend the match then replace the extended match with \1 - the organization line without leading spaces - removing the unwanted lines.
However, when I try to extend it to match subsequent lines as well (e.g. by adding a \n to the end), it matches everything (KATE highlights all the characters in the file as matching).
    ^\s+([^\(]+\(\d+\))$\n

I find this bizarre. I thought the \n would simply take me to the start of the next line but it now matches down to the next organization name line (I still get the same number of matches reported so I know it's stopping there).
I've heard that KATE sometimes gets confused by the "^" at the start, but removing it and/or the "$" doesn't change the behaviour.
Any ideas on what's going on and how to fix it?
Thanks.
BTW: I don't know if this is related but I did a fresh install of Trixie several days ago, so a lot of things might not have the same settings I used to use. I've been using \n in multiline matches for years without this issue.

OK, I still don't know why the first expression doesn't work right, so I rewrote it to be more specific. In particular, every organization name starts with a capital letter so I wrote that into the match expression as:
\s+([A-Z].+\(\d+\))\n

then to get the remaining lines to match, I added
([\s].*\n)+

to the end. The initial \s is because all the lines I wanted erased begin with spaces. Hitting a line without a leading space means I'm at the Officer information.
The replace line is simply
\1\n

I still don't know why the [^(]+(\d+)\n match matched all the other lines. If someone can clue me in, I'd appreciate it.
Thanks.

[^(]+ matches all characters but ( including line break, so, after the first match of (id) regex engine matches every thing until the next org...(id). It's better to use .+? or [(\r\n]+

I would say [^(\r\n]+.
